# Update SQLite table with values from 1 to N

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some table in `SQLite` that has a column named `Numbers`. This table contains `N` elements. I want to create some kind of an update query that allows me to change `Numbers`' values for `1-N`.

I wanted to add a new column that autoincrements (so it would be exactly as I want to). Then copy values from my temporary column to `Numbers` (I don't want to rename it to avoid dealing with constraints). Then drop the temp column. But... The problem is `SQLite` doesn't support anything like `RENAME COLUMN/DELETE COLUMN` for `ALTER TABLE`.

How can I update my column in such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a temp table;
2. Populate it with primary key (use `ROWID` if none) and new computed `Numbers`;
3. `UPDATE your_table SET Numbers=(SELECT Numbers FROM temp_table WHERE id=your_table.id) WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp_table)`
4. Drop temp table.

Comment: Didn't notice that ROWID is a default field that can be simply copied:) Thanks