# What is the most efficient way to do rows ordering in SQLite table?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I need to keep order of about 4000 rows in SQLite table. Inserting and deleting of rows need to be quick operation.

Current solution: I have integer column Ord. After every insertion Ord in new row just gets next integer so no need to change old rows but after deletion sometimes I need to re-populate almost all 4000 rows and it takes too long (~10s). For updating of this column I use this solution 
[Update SQLite table with values from 1 to N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490033/update-sqlite-table-with-values-from-1-to-n)

Is there a better way to maintain ordering?

Comment: If you're just looking for *ordering*, why do you need to update existing rows? Presumably the order will still be correct, right? Just some numbers may be skipped.

Comment: Yes but c# logic can fetch only consecutive values - it assumes sequential values in this column. Changing this logic would be expensive at this point.

Comment: Are you trying to Shrink the `Ord` column?  Basically, on deletion renumber all records that were after the record deleted.

Comment: If you're always deleting one row (or a known number of rows which are together), you could always do `UPDATE table SET Ord=Ord-1 WHERE Ord>@DeletedOrdNumber` or something to that effect. Would imagine that's vastly less espensive than re-ordering the entire table in a temp table.

Comment: Glorin's approach looks promising. However from time to time random rows are deleted at once. I will try the approach and get back here.

Comment: Longer term, the correct solution would probably be to simply add an insertion datetime column to the table, put an index on it, and use an `ORDER BY` clause when querying. Explicitly managing your ordering like this is asking for pains.

Comment: UPDATE MyTable SET Ord=Ord-1 takes 35s and journal file grows up to 1.3Gb (same as my db size)
connBuilder.JournalMode = SQLiteJournalModeEnum.Off removed journal file and operation lasts 13s

Comment: Define "better way", what criteria do you use here to judge if a solution is better? The real better way would be to use `ORDER BY` when requesting the rows and not have the client rely on all numbers being present.

Comment: Is "Ord" the primary key or just an extra column?

Comment: Ord is indexed extra column. Better way means faster/more efficient way.

Comment: I prefer having Ord column instead insertion Timestamp because user will have possibility to reorder items manually. Doing paging, caching and especially maintaining correct scroll bar position would be hard without clean Ord column - rewriting those is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by moving Ord column out from my main table MyTable (which has 21 other columns!) into new Ordering table with just two columns: Ordering.MyTableId and Ordering.Ord. 
All operations (including complete clearing and re-inserting 4000 rows) on this new table execute in 2 seconds!